# Why am I getting ' org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize' when the class is serialized?

Tags: java, hibernate

```
@Table(name="Article")
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
public class Articles implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -6652995014527706545L;

  public Articles() {
      OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.now();
//    Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(dateTime.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Z")).toLocalDateTime());
      this.timeStamp = dateTime;
  }

  @Column(name = "timeStamp")
    @Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
    private OffsetDateTime timeStamp;

    public OffsetDateTime getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(OffsetDateTime timeStamp) {

}
```

I have few other class variables, but only after adding timeStamp variable, I got this issue

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found it by myself. Using java.time import was the issue. I should be using sql.time. And it resolved it.